# Swift Playground on iPad issue with zoomed app

Tags: swift, swiftui, ipad-playgrounds

I try to create simple calculator app for study purpose but when I try to preview the result it’s zoomed and not in correct size.

this is my sample code:

```
struct CalculatorView: View {
    
    var buttonTypes: [[ButtonType]] {
        [[.allClear, .negative, .percent, .operation(.division)],
         [.digit(.seven), .digit(.eight), .digit(.nine), .operation(.multiplication)],
         [.digit(.four), .digit(.five), .digit(.six), .operation(.subtraction)],
         [.digit(.one), .digit(.two), .digit(.three), .operation(.addition)],
         [.digit(.zero), .decimal, .equals]]
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            displayText
            buttonPad
        }
        .padding(Constants.padding)
        .background(Color.black)
    }
    
}
```

[image: Result]

I try to put the View in Frame with Width and Height but don’t work. I expect that the app is look correct in full screen on every devices